# Find a href and match a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have this variabele.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

I get the href from a link. Now i have a lot of display none div's on the page. I want to check if the div have the same id. The id that is in the href. Then the div must be show.

How can i make that check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate your `href` variable with a number sign to produce a [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), and call [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) on your returned object:

```
$('#' + href).show();
```

Comment: Is `.` a correct concatenator? Seems more like PHP to me. JS normally uses `+`.

Comment: `+` for javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you have a bunch of hidden DIVs that you want to show based on the anchor ID. the code below should work however you should not have more than one ID on a page no matter what element it is assigned to. Best practice is to use classes. It would work the same.

```
// create a click function for the anchor tag
$('a').click(function(){
    //grab the id of the selected anchor tag if if has one if not it will be undefined.
    // $(this) represents the current anchor tag in the scope of the click function.
    var href = $(this).attr('id');
    // look for any other element with the same id and set it to show.
    $('#'+href).show();
    // cancel the anchor page action.
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

that's True when using JQuery Selector you can Use Exact

```
$('#' + href + '').show();
```

Comment: `$('#' + href)` works fine. You don't need the additional empty string.